# Change multiple filenames by replacing a character in folder and subfolders

Tags: rename, batch-rename

I use this code

```
rename 's/\:/-/g' *.png -vn
```

to replace : with - in all files in a folder...

But I need to rename all files in a specific folder and its subfolders like this.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find folder -type f -iname '*.png' | rename -vn 's/\:/-/g'
```

Or:

```
find folder -type f -iname '*.png' -exec rename -vn 's/\:/-/g' {} +
```

Or bash's recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -vn 's/\:/-/g' folder/**/*.png
```

Comment: bash: /usr/bin/rename: argument list too long...

Comment: @GennaroSantoro if there are too many files, use the `find` method instead

Comment: @muru does `rename` have -0 flag ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy not that I know of.

Comment: The `find` solutions will result in "No such file" error messages if there's a directory matching `-iname '*.png'` that contains at least one (grand-)child matching `-iname '*.png'`. You either need to exclude directories from the search with `! -type d` or use `-depth` to list directory content first so that (grand-)children can be renamed before their (grand-)parents.